# Software update, itunes, App Store cannot connect to Internet on Mac Mini v10.6.8

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

I update my Mac Mini from OS X v10.6.3 to v10.6.8, it was successful.

I found out that iTunes cannot connect to iTunes store. The software update can't check for updates, and the App Store cannot connect to the App Store.

Yes I have good Internet connection, I can surf Internet in safari.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your date and time preferences are set to the Apple servers.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem on the Mac App Store. I have not been able to reach it for the last 24 hours. I am getting the same error: "Cannot connect to the App Store" and "An Internet connection is required".

Nothing to do, but wait.